# Blazor WebAssembly loading Issues

Tags: deployment, blazor, blazor-webassembly, .net-7.0

We have created a Blazor application with WebAssembly.
Everything worked great, and the first feedback from the beta tester was good.

Now we had a last test round, before the release and faced a big issue on some machines.
On some machines, the init loading will never succeed, and the user only sees the loading screen.

After research, we found out, that some company policies, block "dll" downloads so the application cannot run.

To fix this we checked out the article, from Microsoft, about the hosting (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/host-and-deploy/webassembly?view=aspnetcore-7.0)

So we added the following property:

```
<RunAOTCompilation>true</RunAOTCompilation>
```

This fixes the issue, but now the first loading is very slow. It takes about 2-4 minutes until the page is loaded...

Can someone help us to fix our issue?

Comment: I am not an expert, but I think this question cannot be answered beacause we cannot know why your app takes very long to load. However here are some best practices from the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/performance?view=aspnetcore-7.0#ahead-of-time-aot-compilation)